# Chinese Chilli Oil for high heat cooking

Tags: food-science

I recently made **Chinese Chilli Oil** (with sunflower oil) and loved the flavour it brings into other dishes. I'm thinking of **high heat stir frying** with this oil.
Will high heat burn the chilli flavours in the oil? Should I just stick with adding some at the end of cooking to impart the flavour?

Comment: There is no problem. There are actually a few dishes in Szechuan cuisine where chili oil is cooked over high heat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info Xuanrui. Btw, are there any tips you could give me to enhance flavour of chinese cuisine. I mean techniques that the local chinese people use.

Comment: Whoa, this sounds like a big question. Chinese cuisine is diverse; different regions have completely different cooking methods. You might want to be more specific, and also ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done plenty of experimentation with chili oils in the past, my experience was that chili suspended in the oil seems to be able to stand up to high heat, but any solids will smoke and add off flavors. Filtering my chili oils worked well, however there's a lot of variation chilis, oils and how much heat your stove can produce and you aren't going to really know until you cook with it. I'd start with something simple like green beans and work your way up from there.